# Correct configuration for adding an earth terminal block?

Tags: grounding, safety, earth, neutral, chassis

I have a small motor controller test board setup like the diagram below:

[image: rough circuit diagram]

A few loads such as a motor controller, and some switches are connected to the live and neutral terminal blocks for power. These are mounted on a DIN rail. For safety purposes, I want to earth the DIN rail, and would like to connect it as per the diagram.

My question is, if the neutral wire (circled in red) was cut or somehow disconnected, would the Earth terminal block connection allow the DIN rail to become energised? Let's say one of the loads was a LED, would there be a positive voltage now at the neutral terminal blocks, and therefore also the DIN rail?

A sub-question would be, is this the best practice way to earth the DIN rail?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how.

[image]

Please note:

1. The 'Com' terminal of the 24 V Power Supply should be connected to
   'PE' (protective earth).
2. The 'Com' terminal should not be connected to 'N' (neutral).
3. 'N' should not be connected to 'PE'.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, unfortunately neither my motor controller nor PSU has a separate connection terminal for earth. The PSU is an adapter type with a DC jack plug. In this case I think I will just leave out the Earth terminal block for my test board.

Comment: Anytime, Dominic! In that case only the motor would require protective earthing.